# Maven-Shade MySQL classnotfound

Tags: java, maven, mysql-connector

I'm trying to use Maven Shade to build an Uber Jar. Everything is working, it builds makes the uber jar, which I'm running from a BAT file: non database stuff runs fine, but for some reason, MySQL-Connector is not being found on the classpath.

```
2014-09-08 17:14:00 DEBUG DatabaseConnectionFactory:47 - Creating a new database connection
2014-09-08 17:14:00 ERROR DatabaseConnectionFactory:53 - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB?user=root&password=
```

The maven plugins are located in my parent POM, and the dependencies are in the child poms, ( though I've tried putting the plugins in the DB module POM too, to no avail.)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.32</version>
</dependency>
```

In seeking a solution, I've adding -cp to the downloaded jar on the command line, but I can't get the connector found! The whole program works in my IDE fine, no issues.

I've read a couple of other posts involving Shade, from which I never found a clear enough ( clear enough for me ( no comments please) answer!) The answers usually stipulated using assembly plugin. However, I'd like to stick with Shade as it makes everything simple.

I've added a cut down POM below, and am hoping someone can help me out!

Many thanks!

```
               <execution>
                    <id>myClient</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>C:\Dev\myJar.jar</outputFile>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>myapp.ClientStart</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>

                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>properties/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>images/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Comment: Never used shade, only assembly plugin, but please check if you jar has the mysql package. If it doesn't than you know it's a plugin configuration issue.

Comment: @dimoniy Why not using maven-shade-plugin? What's the matter?

Comment: I am having the same problem. And it happens with both the assembly as well as the shade plugin. There is only 1 java.sql.Driver implementation in my project. META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver exists and is correct. If I add a Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") as the first line of my main entry point there is no exception, but it doesn't fix the 
problem.

Comment: Shade works fine for me now. But in terms of helping you out, I'm comparing my current pom.xml, and I can't see anything that I did differently from what's above. I added the <createDependencyReducedPom  as I pointed out.

Comment: @Gert Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Try referencing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in Java code (not in string literal) for any valid syntax that doesn't affect performance, e.g. a simple line `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getName();` which is a meaningless call to a getter that does nothing. This will be shaded by the shade plugin and cause autoloaders to autoload the class.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your shaded JAR contains a resource `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` with contents

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

If it doesn't, there might be some other JDBC driver in your dependencies which superseded the MySQL resource.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the problem, but I'm still working out how! I have two <execution> tags, one for client and one for server. I swapped the order of these, and set                         <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>. However, I can't see how this affected anything pertinent. Interestingly, what is in the /services/ directory in the jar is java.sql.Driver. But anyway, it seems to be working now. Thank you for your answer. What a great plugin it is!

Comment: One other thing: we had a problem this week with this. Thought  I'd give a heads up. I had dependency on SQL Server and MySQL jars; for our project it's an either or situation: we don't need both in any one client build. Having two did create a problem: I was getting no driver found errors: Having only one jar in the final shade fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. I had both H2 and postgres drivers as dependencies. Removing H2 allowed the postgres driver to work. The java.sql.Driver file was being overwritten with the one from H2.

Comment: If anyone else finds this to be the case, please indicate, and I can post it an answer.